# SQL: combine two columns into one query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that represents cameras' configuration.

Say that a camera with primary key *x* has the following configuration, as a json string which I later use as a dictionary in python: `{A:[...], B:[...]}`

Now we decided to add an entry for the table with primary key null, which will be set as a project default. There will only be one entry in the table with the primary key as null, say that its configuration column value is `{A:[...], C:[...]}`.

At the moment I use a very simple query to return the cameras and their configuration:

```
SELECT pk, configuration FROM static.cameras
```

Is there a way to return the cameras with their configurations, but fill the missing keys from the project defaults, if available?
 so for each key in the string, **if the camera does not have it**, it will fill it up from the default one. Example:

```
|  pk  |  configuration  |
|  01  |[A:10, B:20, C:1]|
|  02  |[A:200, B:3]     |
|  03  |[D:1000]         |
| NULL |[A:0, D:2]       |
```

The result of the wanted query will be:

```
01    [A:10, B:20, C:1, D:2]
02    [A:200, B:3, D:2]
03    [A:0, D:1000]
```

I know it's easy to do it with python after the query, looping over the results, but is there a way to do it using SQL syntax?

Comment: This might be easier to do in Python.  Basically, you need to loop through the defaults that exist and check/add them into the JSON.  I don't think that is easy in MySQL.

Comment: Just to be sure, the NULL pk are the defaults?

Comment: @DownloadPizza correct, and there will be only one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `configuration` is contains valid JSON objects, you can use `json_contains_path()` for filtering and `json_set()` to update the value:

```
update mytable set configuration  = json_set(configuration, '$.D', 2)
where not json_contains_path(configuration, '$.D')
```